How to create a container bigger than the content in CeTZ?
I want to create for example a rectangle/triangle/circle/ellipse that is as big as it's contents, in cetz, how can I do that?
#import "@preview/cetz:0.2.2"
#import cetz.draw: *
#import cetz.styles: *


#cetz.canvas({
import cetz.draw: *
// Example usage
circle((0, 0), name: "circle", radius: 1)
content((0,0),"hello, but this is bigger")
})

I would like to avoid hardcoding the size of the container, since I don't want to manually do it for every single node.

You can use the typst circle instead of cetz.draw.circle; the only downside is anchors are relative to the content's box, rather than the circle edges. Note in this example I import draw as d instead of draw: * so the builtin circle doesn't get shadowed:
#import "@preview/cetz:0.2.2"
#cetz.canvas({
import cetz.draw as d
d.content((0,0), align(center + horizon, circle[This will get bigger]), name: "a")
d.line("a.south-west", (rel: (-1, -1)), name: "b")
})



This is courtesy of CeTZ creator, a funcion that adapts to the size, it has 2 options, circle, ellipse, and accepts an arbitrary function that can make whichever shape using your own custom logic. Needs work.
#import "@preview/cetz:0.2.2"
#import cetz: canvas, draw, plot, chart, coordinate, palette, tree, vector

//#{type(canvas)==function}
#let frame(a,body) = {
  (ctx => {
    let (ctx, drawables, bounds) = cetz.process.many(ctx, cetz.util.resolve-body(ctx, body))

    let center = cetz.vector.lerp(bounds.low, bounds.high, 0.5)
    let rx = 1 / calc.cos(45deg) * (bounds.high.at(0) - center.at(0))
    let ry = 1 / calc.sin(45deg) * (bounds.high.at(1) - center.at(1))
    let m=calc.max(rx,ry)
    
    
      if a==1 {//ellipse
         
      drawables.push(cetz.drawable.ellipse(..center, rx, ry, stroke: black))} 
      else if a==2 { //circle
      drawables.push(cetz.drawable.ellipse(..center, m, m, stroke: black))
      } else if type(a)==function {//we are a function!
        drawables=a(drawables,center,rx,ry)
      }else{ //default, error?
      drawables.push(cetz.drawable.arc(0,0,0,0deg,129deg,1 ,6,fill:red))
    
    }
    
    if ctx.debug {
      drawables.push(
        cetz.drawable.path(("line", bounds.low, (bounds.low.at(0), bounds.high.at(1), 0), bounds.high, (bounds.high.at(0), bounds.low.at(1), 0)), close: true, stroke: red))
    }
    
    return (
      ctx: ctx,
      drawables: drawables,
    )
  },)
}

#cetz.canvas(debug: false,{
  import cetz.draw: *

  frame((drawables,center,rx,ry)=>{
  drawables.push(cetz.drawable.ellipse(..center, rx, ry, stroke: black))
  //drawables.push(cetz.drawable.content(center, rx, ry, "",[\ #rx])) //to debug
  //(close: false, fill: none, stroke: none, segments)
  //drawables.push(cetz.drawable.path(close:false,fill:none,stroke:black,
  //((1,1),(2,2))
//))
  return drawables
},{
    //circle((0,1))
    //rect((4,3), (rel: (2,1)))
    
    content((3,-2), [Das ist ein kleiner Text!], angle: 0deg)
  })
})


As refered to here :https://github.com/cetz-package/cetz/issues/740#issuecomment-2457796488
You can use a content frame to scale a circle or rectangle around text :
#import "@preview/cetz:0.3.1"

#cetz.canvas({
  import cetz.draw: *
  content(
    (0, 0),
    [cont],
    fill: rgb(50, 50, 255, 100),
    stroke: rgb("#000000"),
    frame: "circle",
    padding: 5pt,
  )
})

